# How to use SupportFragmentManager with MvvmCross MvxActivity

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross, supportmapfragment

I'm adding SupportMapFragment to my MvvmCross based activity and instance of SupportFragmentManager is not available from withing MvxActivity context.

SupportFramgentManager is inherited  from FragmentActivity but my activity is already inherited from MvvmCross's MvxActivity.
How to deal with the conjunction of MvvmCross and SupportMapFragment in this case?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging`. In there you have `MvxFragmentActivity`, `MvxFragment` and many more types to use.

There is even a sample here: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Fragments

And a MvvmCross N+1 video about it here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=uQT3_WXQQr0

And a whole series of videos here: https://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/

Comment: Works like a magic! Thank you very much for pointing to the MvxFragmentActivity and thank you for links (bow)